# Use multiple function to `cbind` nested list

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, nested-lists

I want to use `cbind` to nested list with dataframe.

Let's take an example. `nested` is nested list. It has 2 element, and each elements has 2 data.frame. So, `nested` is

1st element = data.frame 1 + data.frame2/
2nd element = data.frame 1 + data.frame 2

```
given<-replicate(2,list(data.frame(unlist(replicate(10,sample(c(0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1),2,replace=FALSE),simplify=FALSE)),ncol=2)))
colnames(given[[1]])<-c('a','b')
colnames(given[[2]])<-c('a','b')
nested<-list(given, given)
```

I'm trying to cbind `nested` data.frame's second column, which is `b` with `target`, which is one 10*2 data.frame. So, it will generated 1 list with 4 elements, which are dataframe.

```
target<-data.frame(sample(c("a","b","c","d"),10,replace=TRUE),sample(c("a","b","c","d"),10,replace=TRUE))
colnames(target)<-c("1st","2nd")
target
```

I tried `lapply` function.

```
last<-lapply(seq_along(nested), function(x) function(y) cbind(target, nested[[x]][[y]][,c("b")]))
```

However, it generated error.

```
[[1]]
function (y) 
cbind(target, nested[[x]][[y]][,c("b")]))
<bytecode: 0x00000000e092abe0>
<environment: 0x00000000e0948390>
```

There must be a problem, but I can't find why. I would really appreciate all your help.

*additional information : I write the expected outcome.

The `nested` is as follows.

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
        a   b
 [1,] 0.3 0.3
 [2,] 0.2 0.4
 [3,] 0.1 0.2
 [4,] 0.3 0.3
 [5,] 0.3 0.4
 [6,] 0.1 0.2
 [7,] 0.3 0.4
 [8,] 0.2 0.3
 [9,] 0.1 0.3
[10,] 0.3 0.4

[[1]][[2]]
        a   b
 [1,] 0.3 0.2
 [2,] 0.4 0.4
 [3,] 0.2 0.4
 [4,] 0.4 0.1
 [5,] 0.1 0.4
 [6,] 0.4 0.3
 [7,] 0.1 0.4
 [8,] 0.4 0.2
 [9,] 0.2 0.4
[10,] 0.4 0.2


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
        a   b
 [1,] 0.3 0.3
 [2,] 0.2 0.4
 [3,] 0.1 0.2
 [4,] 0.3 0.3
 [5,] 0.3 0.4
 [6,] 0.1 0.2
 [7,] 0.3 0.4
 [8,] 0.2 0.3
 [9,] 0.1 0.3
[10,] 0.3 0.4

[[2]][[2]]
        a   b
 [1,] 0.3 0.2
 [2,] 0.4 0.4
 [3,] 0.2 0.4
 [4,] 0.4 0.1
 [5,] 0.1 0.4
 [6,] 0.4 0.3
 [7,] 0.1 0.4
 [8,] 0.4 0.2
 [9,] 0.2 0.4
[10,] 0.4 0.2
```

and `target` is..

```
   1st 2nd 
1    a   b 
2    a   a 
3    c   a 
4    b   a 
5    b   b 
6    c   c 
7    d   b 
8    a   a 
9    c   a 
10   d   b
```

Each data.frame of `nested` has 2 columns, which are `a` and `b`. My expected outcome is...

```
[1]
       1st 2nd   b
    1    a   b   0.3
    2    a   a   0.4
    3    c   a   0.2
    4    b   a   0.3
    5    b   b   0.4
    6    c   c   0.2
    7    d   b   0.4
    8    a   a   0.3
    9    c   a   0.3
    10   d   b   0.4


[2]
       1st 2nd   b
    1    a   b   0.2
    2    a   a   0.4
    3    c   a   0.4
    4    b   a   0.1
    5    b   b   0.4
    6    c   c   0.3
    7    d   b   0.4
    8    a   a   0.2
    9    c   a   0.4
    10   d   b   0.2


[3]
       1st 2nd   b
    1    a   b   0.3
    2    a   a   0.4
    3    c   a   0.2
    4    b   a   0.3
    5    b   b   0.4
    6    c   c   0.2
    7    d   b   0.4
    8    a   a   0.3
    9    c   a   0.3
    10   d   b   0.4


[4]
       1st 2nd   b
    1    a   b   0.2
    2    a   a   0.4
    3    c   a   0.4
    4    b   a   0.1
    5    b   b   0.4
    6    c   c   0.3
    7    d   b   0.4
    8    a   a   0.2
    9    c   a   0.4
    10   d   b   0.2
```

Comment: Do you want to add `target` to each nested dataframe so `target` will be added 4 times?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I will add 'nested' to 'target' 4 times. I generated 'target', but I dropped the code by mistake. I'm on the cell-phone now so I can't write the code.

Comment: It worked but I want to cbind second column of data.frames in `nested`, which is `b`.

Comment: Sorry for not delivering my question well. I write the expected outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use nested `lapply` and get the `"b"` column from each list and `cbind` it with `target`

```
lapply(nested, function(x) lapply(x, function(y) cbind(target, b = y[["b"]])))
```